# After upgrading Grails withCriteria query no longer working

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I recently updated a Grails project to the latest *2.x* version, 2.5.0, along with all the dependencies, including Hibernate, which is now at 4.3.5.2.

Everything *mostly* works, i.e. the database is writing/retrieving values fine, controllers do their thing, Spring security works, etc. However, now one of the model queries using `withCriteria` is throwing a weird error.

The two domain classes look something like this:

```
class MyModel1 {
   Integer status
   MyModel2 model2
}

class MyModel2 {
   Integer range1
   Integer range2 
}
```

And then I have this method that does a query that checks the "range" fields of the sub-model:

```
public List<MyModel1> doThing(int low, int hi) {

    return MyModel1.withCriteria {
        eq("status", SomeStatus.FLAGGED)
        model2 {
            between("range1", low, hi)
            between("range2", low*2, hi*3)
        }
    }
}
```

Prior to upgrading, this code worked fine. Now it complains with the following exception:

```
could not resolve property: model2_alias0 of: com.example.MyModel2. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: model2_alias0 of: com.example.MyModel2
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(CriteriaBuilder.java:329)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_withCriteria_closure11.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:305)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria(GormStaticApi.groovy:304)
    at com.example.MyService.doThing(MyService.groovy:42)
```

(Additionally, I'm using IntelliJ, and when I highlight the `between()` statements in the above `withCriteria` block IntelliJ informs me that it "Cannot resolve symbol 'between'". Maybe not relevant, IDK.)

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the problem was with the version of Hibernate to which I'd updated.

The clue was in the [2.5.0 GORM docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/GORM.html) where it states:

> Under the hood it uses Hibernate 3 ...

I was trying to use v4, as I state above. I switched back to the latest version of 3. Put the following in **BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
plugins {
   runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.19"
}
```

Also had to switch this line in **DataSource.groovy**:

```
hibernate {
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // had been this: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
```

After that, everything works as it should. (Also, IntelliJ still complains about the `between` clause, so apparently, *not* relevant.)